Git get theirs commit hash
When git working tree is in conflict state during merge/rebase/cherry-pick, it's possible to get ours/theirs/base version of individual files by several ways, e.g. git checkout --ours/--theirs path/file or git show :n:path/file where n is 1, 2 or 3, see e.g. Git: get ours/theirs file content during merge
However, I would like to get ours and theirs commit hashes (SHA). For ours it's simple: git rev-parse HEAD. But for theirs I have to try git rev-parse for preudorefs MERGE_HEAD, REBASE_HEAD, CHERRY_PICK_HEAD, REVERT_HEAD, ... (... is for maybe more pseudorefs? E.g. what pseudoref has stash pop conflict?). Is there any simple way to get theirs commit hash for all scenarios simply and reliably?

You can specify -s --format=%H to git-show to get just the oid.

@WilliamPursell It does not work with git show :n:path/file to show file content. I can get file oid by git rev-parse :n:path/file, but I want commit oid, see the question.

I am not aware of a function that would make this simple. You have to try all of them, or at least the one that pertains to the operation that caused the conflict.


Is there any simple way to get theirs commit hash for all scenarios simply and reliably?

There's no requirement that there be a commit hash for it. Git will already construct a base version from multiple merge bases resolving merges that have them, it's already common in some workflows to have a :1:$path revision that's referenced only in the index, that was constructed specially.
Also: anyone doing something Git doesn't already have a convenience command for can load the index arbitrarily (pretty much the same way the existing conveniences do) with git update-index --index-info or --cacheinfo or --info-only.
You could ls `git rev-parse --git-dir`/*_HEAD and ignore FETCH_HEAD to get all the _HEADs of commands that follow the existing naming convention, and walk through their content looking for a match.
path=example.c
pathrev=`git rev-parse :3:$path`
for head in `git rev-parse --git-dir`/*_HEAD
do if test x`git rev-parse ${head##*/}:$path 2>&-` = x$pathrev
then git rev-parse ${head##*/}
fi; done

will do it for existing commands.

Thanks for the explanation for base, but IMO theirs should be same commit for all conflicting files.

@xmedeko And the code snippet will work for all the common cases. I agree synthetic tip content is going to be even rarer than crisscross merge bases but I can imagine for instance a tool to allow merging multiple partial conflict resolutions.
